# trying to get property of non object in script on line 102

Tags: php

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div class="post" title="Timestamp: '. $row["clock"] .'">';
        echo '<div class="handle"><div class="tripcode">' . $row["tripcode"]. '</div><div class="user">&lt;<div class="name">'. $row["handle"]. '</div>&gt;</div></div><div class="message">' . $row["message"]. '</div><br>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

source code = http://pastebin.com/qahkB6mt

the error i got was:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/h1/206/469206/public_html/h/chat.php on line 102

0 results

Comment: it's a notice not an error. Do you have records on your database? because you are executing the code in the else condition

Comment: It might be nice if you were to indicate which is line 102 in this 12 line code fragment

Comment: The most likely reason is that the query failed. As you dont bother checking for that maybe you should

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.